# Base64 a Pdf Nodejs Handlebars

Tags: javascript, nodejs, pdf, base64, handlebars.js

Hola estoy intentando descargar un pdf que traigo de mi base de datos de sql, el archivo lo tengo almacenado en base64,y lo recibo directo de mi query como un buffer, lo que realmente quiero es pasarle ese archivo a un **anchor** `<a herf=""/>` para que pueda darle click y descargarlo, o renderearlo. Usando Nodejs y handlebars

Este es mi objeto desde la terminal.

```
  onepayer: <Buffer 4a 56 42 45 52 69 30 78 4c 6a 4d 4b 4a 63 54 6c 38 75 58 72 70 2f 4f 67 30 4d 54 47 43 6a 51 67 4d 43 42 76 59 6d 6f 4b 50 44 77 67 4c 30 78 6c 62 6d ... >,
```

Y este mi código.

```
router.get('/pdfuser/:id', isLoggedIn, async (req, res) => {
const {
    id
} = req.params;
const admin = await pool.query('Select * from pdfs where id_user  = ?', [id]);


console.log(admin[0])

res.render('links/edit', {
    admin: admin[0]
});
```

});

Usando handle bars recibo todo string de base64 en la variable **{{pdf.onepayer}}** , pero no sé como renderar o pasarle este o un anchor o algo para descargarla, quizá pasarlo por una función, pero es una variable de handlebars y no sé si la puede meter en un script.

Answer (score 1):

Podrías crear un objecto de tipo `Blob` a partir de ese buffer, y con él una URL que se podría descargar con un enlace. Por ejemplo:

```js
const decoded = window.atob(pdf.onepayer)
const decodedLength = decoded.length
const decodedArray = new Uint8Array(decodedLength)
for (let i = 0; i < decodedLength; ++i) {
  decodedArray[i] = decoded.charCodeAt(i)
}
const blob = new Blob([decodedArray], {type: 'application/pdf'})
const blobUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob)
const a = document.createElement('a')
a.setAttribute('href', blobUrl)
a.setAttribute('download', '')
a.appendChild(document.createTextNode('Descargar PDF'))
document.body.appendChild(a)
```

Si necesitas que sea compatible con IE, tendrás que usar [`msSaveBlob`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh772331(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: Oye está bastante bien, pero hay un par de preguntas que quissiera hacer, primero si descarla mi pdf pero en un fomarto ilegible, me gustaría darle un bombre particualr a este archivo y por último, puedes decirme como heredarlo a un div en particular para que no me lo tiré hasta el final del body?

Comment: Tienes razón, no estaba decodificando el contenido de base64 a binario. ¿Puedes probar ahora con el código editado, por favor?

Comment: Estoy obteniendo este error en el atob() > String contains an invalid character

Comment: ¿Podrías probar a convertir el `Buffer` en `string` antes de enviarlo? Por ejemplo: `res.render('links/edit', {
    admin: admin[0].toString('ascii')
});`

Comment: lo intenté , incluso usé un query para el puro pdf ,pero me devuelve un [Obj obj]